# How to change font size on Mobile?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this html code that shows on desktop. How do I can add the specific mobile code so I can reduce the font size to 35 px on mobile?

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;" class="sapMktBlock">
<h3 class="mobileheader" style="margin: 10px 0px 30px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: normal; font-family: Baskerville; font-size: 50px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; display: block; color: #000000 !important; text-align: center;">Looks Like Something <br />Caught Your Eye</h3>
<table class="deviceWidth" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse !important; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS media queries?

Comment: I always use a font of `2.3vh` for small fonts, and something like `4.5vh` for large ones. Always responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Media Queries like this.

Mobile Viewport sizes varies from 360 x 740, where 360 is width and 740 is height

```
@media (max-width:360px){
    // Write your code Here, for example
    .my-text{
        font-size:12px;
        color : red;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of using `css` units `vh` and `vw`:

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 7vh;">Becomes bigger on mobile devices</h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 7vw;">Becomes smaller on mobile devices</h1>
```

Comment: My choice of `7vh and vw` is an example. Use an online css-converter, like (https://sabe.io/tools/css-unit-conversion-calculator), to find the optimal value;

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are your best option for this, just do what ZeevhY Org. posted

Place it at the bottom of your CSS file or bottom of you script tag

```
@media (max-width:the max pixel value you want it to apply at(you can also do min)){
    // Write your code Here, for example
    .my-text{
        font-size:12px;
        color : red;    
    }
}
```

note: if you have multiple overlapping media queries you might need to use !important on some CSS tags so they apply.

Comment: I don't have experience using media queries, so where would I place them?